# Trying to save a blob file in Outlook for macOS using javascript

Tags: javascript, macos, outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

Ok so I have a `Blob` file that I'm trying to save on local disk (the `Blob` is created locally from an `ArrayBuffer`). The problem I'm facing is that Outlook for macOS does not want to open a `FileSaverDialog` or something similar to let the user save the file.

### My code is working perfectly in Outlook for Web (OWA) on all browsers (including Safari) and Outlook for Windows.

```
const blob = new Blob([body]); //body is an ArrayBuffer created locally
const link = document.createElement('a');
if (link.download !== undefined) {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.setAttribute('href', url);
    link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

**PS:** I have tried using `window.open(blob);`, but Outlook for macOS throws an error in that situation: *"There is no application set to open URL blob:https://..."*

**PS 2:** I have also tried using `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { height: 100, width: 100, requireHTTPS: true });`,but still getting the same error.

How am I supposed to prompt a `SaveFileDialog` for the user ? Thank you in advance

**EDIT** Microsoft seems to be working on a patch for this